# Displaying Text Documents in an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to create a webpage which will load .tx files from the same directory and display the contents as diiferent sections on the page. after some searching, I found the JQuery which would allow me find and display the text from any given .txt document, however, I am struggling with another aspect.

I want to be able to add any .txt document to the folder with the page, and have it show up the next time I open the page, with no extra code needed. In essence, I will be dropping some text files into the folder and it would be nice for them to show up automatically.

It would be greatly appreaciated if somebody can provide some advice or tell me where to look for an answer, as after a couple of days of searching, it is beginning to frustrate me.

Thanks

Comment: Rayon is right, you should show us what you have done. + If I understand, you want to display each TXT files from the same folder of your HTML page ? Or only those you select ?

Comment: please provide some code of what you've done so far like Rayon said. There are alot of solutions to this depending on what your environment looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar SO questions on how to load all images from a directory and how to load text files. This is adapted:

html:

```
<div id='foundTexts'>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
    var directory = 'texts/';

    $.ajax({
        //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
        url: directory,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            //List all txt file names
            $(data).find("a:contains(.txt)").each(function (i) {
                // find the new file url of each txt file
                var newFileLocation = directory+$(this).text().substring(1);

                $.get(newFileLocation, function(response) {
                    // loads the content of each file, inserts into a list item and appends to an unordered list
                    $("#foundTexts ul").append( '<li>'+ response +'</li><br>');
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Ensure your server folder is configured to be browsable, and that you have the set the `directory` variable to the right folder location for your text files.